# iPhone Caching Issue

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile, ios4, mobile-safari

Okay, here is what I am experiencing. I am building a mobile app with HTML/CSS/JS, and testing it mostly on iPhone before porting to app store with phonegap. But, I am having caching problems when I go into the app (I've added it to my iPhone with the "Add to home screen" feature). It doesn't show the last saved updates immediately like it does when I refresh in the browser. The one thing I am noticing though, is it seems to cache for about an hour or so, and then update. So I'm wondering, does Apple set the cache to save and update on a time schedule, and if so can I disable that? I would prefer to just disable cache while developing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing Safari manually

`Settings -> Safari`

Then select `Clear Cookies and Data`

Then in that same settings panel, at the bottom select `Advanced -> Website Data` and delete the appropriate data.

In your HTML, disable cache might work?

http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/metatags.html